# Adding more items to a group by statement

Tags: c#, linq

I have this query:

```
    var rowsPerProvider = (from row in dt.Select()
        let emp = row["f_name"].ToString().Trim()
        group row by emp
        into g
        select g).ToDictionary(
            g => g.Key,
            g => g.ToArray());
```

How can I update it to also filter on some more columns? for example currently it is on `f_name`. How can I update it to group on `f_name` and `m_name` and `l_name`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make an anonymous object containing the fields you want to group by:

```
var rowsPerProvider = (from row in dt.Select()
    group row by new
    {
        emp1 = row["f_name"].ToString().Trim(),
        emp2 = row["m_name"].ToString().Trim(),
        emp3 = row["l_name"].ToString().Trim(),
    }
    into g
    select g).ToDictionary(
        g => g.Key,
        g => g.ToArray());
```

Comment: thanks, so when we do grouping this way, it ensures that all of them for each key of this dictionary have the same first name, middle name and last name. right?

Comment: @CutHimSomeSlack - yes, the anonymous type has an Equals and GetHashCode that check all the properties are the same - see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12123542/383710

Answer (score 3):

Use anonymous class:

```
// (...)
    group row by new { emp, something }
```