# Ignoring casing on anonymous type string or char members when doing .Distinct()

Tags: c#, linq, distinct

Let's say I have the a list of anonymous objects like this

```
list = [{name: "bob"},{name: "sarah"},{name: "Bob"}]
```

then when I do list.Distinct(), I will get `[{name: "bob"},{name: "sarah"},{name: "Bob"}]`

Is there a way to tell it to ignore casing on string type members and just have it return bob or Bob for the *duplicate* item so the result is `[{name: "bob"},{name: "sarah"}]`

Best I have is hacking around it using `GroupBy` on `.name.ToLower()` - but that's far from ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Distinct` use comparison defined of the type to detect the same object. That means it should check if they are the same reference because they are objects.

This can be checked in https://dotnetfiddle.net/h5AoUZ

In your case, there is no way for .NET to know your criteria to consider `bob` and `Bob` are the same.

One proposition for you. A new Distinct method with a function parameter:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>
    (this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    HashSet<TKey> seenKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
    foreach (TSource element in source)
    {
        if (seenKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
        {
            yield return element;
        }
    }
}
```

And calling

```
list.DistinctBy(x=>x.name.Lower())
```

Comment: https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs may be of interest. _Also consider handling `null`._

Comment: helpful info, noted it to add it in my project

Comment: Anonymous type equality (as used by Distinct) is not done by reference but rather using the default equality comparer, which does a field-by-field equality check  https://stackoverflow.com/q/12123512/491907  (for value types and strings its basically the same semantics of the == operator)

Comment: I think what you are saying is not correct at all. Look at this : https://dotnetfiddle.net/9NoWBB , if same string, it always returns false,

Comment: ToLower is not actually equivalent to case insensitive comparison.