# LINQ Group by different output

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, group-by

I am having a hard time grouping a dbset (EntityFramework) by two fields and sending that output to a strongly typed view.

When I use an anonymous type for the composite key I get the right output. A list containing one item and that item in turn has two or more grouping items.

Now if I use a class instead I get a list of two items and in turn each item has one grouping item.

```
var output = context.Transfers.GroupBy(t=> new { t.TNumber, t.Type}).ToList();

var output2 = context.Transfers.AsEnumerable()
                     .GroupBy(t => new OTSpecs(t.TNumber, t.Type)).ToList();
```

`OTSpecs` is just a simple class, with those public fields and a parameter constructor.

I need to add the `AsEnumerable()` otherwise I get a `System.NotSupportedException` Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities

Also because I need to define the model in the view like this

```
@model IEnumerable<IGrouping<OTSpecs, Transfer>>
```

unless of course it is possible to replace OTSpecs in that line with the anonymous type. But I don't know how.

My question is why those lines of code produce a different output?
Is it possible to define the model in the view replacing the OTSpecs for a anonymous type?

Comment: context.Transfers is a DataTable.  To enumerate through the rows, you need to add "AsEnumerable().  When you have a class you need a List() object for the class like : List<OTSpecs> specs = new List();  Then you should be able to use : specs.Group(t =>  new { t.TNumber, t.Type}).ToList();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anonymous types implement equality comparison which compares [all their properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12123542/728795). So when you are using anonymous type as a key, linq is able to identify that two key objects are same and should be grouped together.

Your custom object, I suspect, does not implement that stuff, so for it just general object comparison is used, which just compares references. Two key objects have difference references - thus different groups.

To fix this, you may need to either pass in [equality comparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__4_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___0___2__System_Func___1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___2____3__System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___1__), or implement `Equals` in your class `OTSpecs`.

Comment: Thanks  @RobertHarvey for making me post a better question and Andrei for the answer. I was not fully aware of that. I implemented Equals and GetHashCode and it is working how I expected.