# Why does Linq join on Nullable<T> not work the same as ==?

Tags: c#, linq, nullable

```
var list1 = new List<(string Foo, DayOfWeek? DayOfWeek)> {("Friday", DayOfWeek.Friday), ("Null", null)};
var list2 = new List<(int Num, DayOfWeek? DayOfWeek)> {(1, DayOfWeek.Friday), (2, DayOfWeek.Friday), (3, null)};

Console.WriteLine("Q1:");
var q1 = from l1 in list1
         from l2 in list2
         where l1.DayOfWeek == l2.DayOfWeek
         group l2.Num by l1.Foo
         into g
         select new {g.Key, Sum = g.Sum()};

foreach (var x in q1)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{x.Key} = {x.Sum}");
}

Console.WriteLine("Q2:");
var q2 = from l1 in list1
         join l2 in list2 on l1.DayOfWeek equals l2.DayOfWeek
         group l2.Num by l1.Foo
         into g
         select new {g.Key, Sum = g.Sum()};

foreach (var x in q2)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{x.Key} = {x.Sum}");
}
```

Output:

```
Q1:
Friday = 3
Null = 3
Q2:
Friday = 3
```

Note that Q2 does not have a value for "Null"!

What this tells me is that the Linq `equals` / `.Join()` does not use an `==` or `.Equals()` evaluation. So, what is it using, and is there a sensible reason why one `Nullable<T>` does not equate to another `Nullable<T>` when the value is `null`?

Comment: Looks like `equals` in LINQ to Objects  uses three-valued logic the way SQL does, where `NULL` isn't equal to anything, not even NULL

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, it does look like that. Is that a bug, or is it by design? And if by design, why does that make sense, when literally everywhere else in the C# universe, `null` is equal to `null`?

Comment: Instead of using NULL use Count() > 0.  The property still exists but is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Nullable.Equals(Object)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.equals?view=netframework-4.8) returns `true` when `HasValue` property is false, and the other parameter is `null`. It seems, that the first query is evaluated correctly.

As for the second query I've changed it to

```cs
var q2 = from l1 in list1
    join l2 in list2 on new { l1.DayOfWeek } equals new { l2.DayOfWeek }
    group l2.Num by l1.Foo
    into g
    select new { g.Key, Sum = g.Sum() };
```

And got the same result with first query.

The reason of this is that [Enumerable.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=netframework-4.8) method works as `inner join` in SQL, according to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-inner-joins)

> If an element in the first collection has no matching elements, it
>   does not appear in the result set. The Join method, which is called by
>   the join clause in C#, implements an inner join.

And null keys are omitted when lookup is created, according to [sources](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,ceafecd091387688).

```cs
internal static Lookup<TKey, TElement> CreateForJoin(IEnumerable<TElement> source, Func<TElement, TKey> keySelector, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer) {
            Lookup<TKey, TElement> lookup = new Lookup<TKey, TElement>(comparer);
            foreach (TElement item in source) {
                TKey key = keySelector(item);
                if (key != null) lookup.GetGrouping(key, true).Add(item);
            }
            return lookup;
        }
```

So, there is nothing related to object equality, the `null` values just skipped during `join`. I've created a custom `EqualityComparer`, passed it to `Join` method and didn't observe any `null` values coming to `Equals` method.

If you try to use [outer join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins) or [group join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupjoin?view=netframework-4.8), and write something like this

```cs
var q3 = list1.GroupJoin(list2, _ => _.DayOfWeek, _ => _.DayOfWeek, (l1, list) =>
    new
    {
        Name = l1.Foo,
        Num = list.Sum(_ => _.Num)
    }
);
```

or this

```cs
var q3 = from l1 in list1
    join l2 in list2 on l1.DayOfWeek equals l2.DayOfWeek into weeks
    from week in weeks.DefaultIfEmpty()
    group week.Num by l1.Foo
    into g
    select new { g.Key, Sum = g.Sum() };
```

you'll get the following output (correct number of rows, but incorrect sum)

```cs
Q3:
Friday = 3
Null = 0
```

because `Num` values are lost during outer join and grouping (missed keys are substituted by default values). It seems, that it's only working, when you use `where` clause without `join` or use workaround above with an anonymous type.

When the key is anonymous type, the equality in join is evaluated correctly, because all anonymous object instances aren't null, created during equality and compared by the `DayOfWeek?` property inside instance (not the instance itself), according this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123512/why-does-the-equals-implementation-for-anonymous-types-compare-fields)

Comment: +1 for the workaround. But it just amplifies my question. Why does the straight equality comparison not work, but the anonymous type comparison does?

Comment: @ShaulsaysISupportMonica Please have a look at updated answer, I've added a lot details of my research:)

Comment: Wow, that's some seriously thorough research. Thanks! I still don't understand why this is the intended behavior, but you deserve answer credit for that, anyway ;-)