# C# Linq GroupBy ==> Class vs Anonymous class --- different result

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```
var rawGroupBEFORE = sqlRaw.GroupBy(x => new
{
    x.ID,
    x.P1,
    x.P2,
    x.P3,
    x.P4,
    x.P5,
    x.P6,
    x.P7,
    x.P8,              
}).ToList();

var rawGroup = sqlRaw.GroupBy(x => new RawDocument
{
    Id = x.ID,
    P1 = x.P1,
    P2 = x.P2,
    P3 = x.P3,
    P4 = x.P4,
    P5 = x.P5,
    P6 = x.P6,
    P7 = x.P7,
    P8 = x.P8,              
}).ToList();
```

And with the data that I have in the `rawGroupBEFORE` 1 element as result. In the `rawGroup` gives me 2 elements ..... wrong grouping.
I have created the class RawDocument using the automatic Visual Studio "create missing property" action.

Any ideas why I should be getting this behavior?

Comment: You are running one query after another. Are results also different if you run just one (comment either first)? Ideally you need present a proof of the problem in a form of [mcve].

Comment: Does `RawDocument` overrides `GetHashCode` and `Equals`?

Comment: @Sinatr the result is always the same if I comment or not..... or if I invert them. Its is always the same.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv No... the class is a plain DTO object with just properties like:  public int Id { get; set; }

Comment: which net version is it? is the variable sqlraw already fetched data (with a tolist()) or might this be run on a sqlserver as a query?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that the anonymous type uses [value equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123512/why-does-the-equals-implementation-for-anonymous-types-compare-fields), while `RawDocument` uses [reference equality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/equality-comparisons). Since each item will get a new `RawDocument` object, none of them will be equal to each other.

[Implement Equality members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/how-to-define-value-equality-for-a-type) for `RawDocument`, or give the GroupBy a IEqualityComparer.

Comment: or in .NET 5: record types: `public record RawDocument(int Id);` or `public record RawDocument
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}` (the latter being mutable)